# I added an event listener on form but it refreshes page instead

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

Can someone help me, I'm trying to use a button that I created with DOM. This button will be used to remove an item, I've tried using both the event listener and event handler but both don't seem to be working and the browser just refreshes the page, here's the code is written below.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Cart Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="big-container">
        <form  onsubmit= "return getTotal(this)" >
            <div class="addToCart">
            <label for="cart" class="label">Add to cart:</label>
            <select name="list" id="list">
                <option value="selectProducts" id="selctProducts">Selct Product</option>
                <option value="Carrot($2)" id="carrot">Carrot</option>
                <option value="Potato($3)" id="potato">Potato</option>
                <option value="Fish($10)" id="fish">Fish</option>
                <option value="Meat($13)" id="meat">Meat</option>
                <option value="Eggs($6)" id="eggs">Eggs</option>
            </select>
            <button id="add" onclick="return addItem(this)">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="carrotSelected"></div>
        <div id="potatoSelected"></div>
        <div id="fishSelected"></div>
        <div id="meatSelected"></div>
        <div id="eggsSelected"></div>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Calculate</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let remove = document.createElement("button");
let textRemove = document.createTextNode("Remove");
remove.appendChild(textRemove);

addItem = () =>{
    let carrot = document.getElementById("carrot");
    let potato = document.getElementById("potato");
    let fish = document.getElementById("fish");
    let meat = document.getElementById("meat");
    let eggs = document.getElementById("eggs");
    let selectProducts = document.getElementById("selectProducts");
    let list = document.getElementById("list");
    let output = list.value;
    let digit = document.createElement("input");



    if(list.value === "selectProducts"){
        alert("Please select a product");
        return false;
    }
    if(list.value === "Carrot($2)"){
        document.querySelector('#carrotSelected').textContent = output;
        document.querySelector('#carrotSelected').style.fontSize = "2rem";
        document.querySelector('#carrotSelected').style.width = "50%";
        document.querySelector('#carrotSelected').style.margin = "0 3rem";
        document.querySelector('#carrotSelected').style.marginBottom = "1rem";
        document.querySelector('#carrotSelected').style.display = "flex";
        document.querySelector('#carrotSelected').style.justifyContent = "space-evenly";
        digit.setAttribute("type", "number");
        document.getElementById("carrotSelected").appendChild(digit);
        document.getElementById("carrotSelected").appendChild(remove);

    
        return false;

    }

    if(list.value === "Potato($3)"){
        document.querySelector('#potatoSelected').textContent = output;
        document.querySelector('#potatoSelected').style.fontSize = "2rem";
        document.querySelector('#potatoSelected').style.width = "50%";
        document.querySelector('#potatoSelected').style.margin = "0 3rem";
        document.querySelector('#potatoSelected').style.marginBottom = "1rem";
        document.querySelector('#potatoSelected').style.display = "flex";
        document.querySelector('#potatoSelected').style.justifyContent = "space-evenly";
        digit.setAttribute("type", "number");
        document.getElementById("potatoSelected").appendChild(digit);
        document.getElementById("potatoSelected").appendChild(remove);
        return false;

    }

    if(list.value === "Fish($10)"){
        document.querySelector('#fishSelected').textContent = output;
        document.querySelector('#fishSelected').style.fontSize = "2rem";
        document.querySelector('#fishSelected').style.width = "50%";
        document.querySelector('#fishSelected').style.margin = "0 3rem";
        document.querySelector('#fishSelected').style.marginBottom = "1rem";
        document.querySelector('#fishSelected').style.display = "flex";
        document.querySelector('#fishSelected').style.justifyContent = "space-evenly";
        digit.setAttribute("type", "number");
        document.getElementById("fishSelected").appendChild(digit);
        document.getElementById("fishSelected").appendChild(remove);
        return false;

    }

    if(list.value === "Meat($13)"){
        document.querySelector('#meatSelected').textContent = output;
        document.querySelector('#meatSelected').style.fontSize = "2rem";
        document.querySelector('#meatSelected').style.width = "50%";
        document.querySelector('#meatSelected').style.margin = "0 3rem";
        document.querySelector('#meatSelected').style.marginBottom = "1rem";
        document.querySelector('#meatSelected').style.display = "flex";
        document.querySelector('#meatSelected').style.justifyContent = "space-evenly";
        digit.setAttribute("type", "number");
        document.getElementById("meatSelected").appendChild(digit);
        document.querySelector('#remove').style.display ="block"
        document.getElementById("meatSelected").appendChild(remove);
        return false;

    }

    if(list.value === "Eggs($6)"){
        document.querySelector('#eggsSelected').textContent = output;
        document.querySelector('#eggsSelected').style.fontSize = "2rem";
        document.querySelector('#eggsSelected').style.width = "50%";
        document.querySelector('#eggsSelected').style.margin = "0 3rem";
        document.querySelector('#eggsSelected').style.marginBottom = "1rem";
        document.querySelector('#eggsSelected').style.display = "flex";
        document.querySelector('#eggsSelected').style.justifyContent = "space-evenly";
        digit.setAttribute("type", "number");
        document.getElementById("eggsSelected").appendChild(digit);
        document.getElementById("eggsSelected").appendChild(remove);

        remove.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            document.querySelector('#eggSelected').style.display = "none";            
        });

        return false;
    }

    return false;

}

removeItem = () => {
    let carrot = document.getElementById("carrot");
    let potato = document.getElementById("potato");
    let fish = document.getElementById("fish");
    let meat = document.getElementById("meat");
    let eggs = document.getElementById("eggs");
    let list = document.getElementById("list");
    let output = list.value;
    let digit = document.createElement("input");

    if(output === "Carrot($2)"){
        document.getElementById("carrotSelected").remove;

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

remove.addEventListener("click", removeItem);
```

**And CSS(if needed)**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.addToCart{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.label{
    font-size: 2rem;
}

#list{
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#submit{
    width: 15%;
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 0 25rem;
}

#add{
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **()** after `.remove`

```
if (output === 'Carrot($2)') {
  document.getElementById('carrotSelected').remove()

  return false
}
```